# Export multiple attachments per point feature from fgdb using python script

Tags: arcpy, python-script-tool

I use the following script for export of attachments from an arcgis fgdb. It is used inside a script tool. I have multiple attachments (relID) for every pointfeature (GLobalID) and I would like to modify it to include export all of those.

How do I achieve this? I would like to be able to distinguish between  attachments which relate to the same pointfeature somehow in the output folder.

Edit:

New code:

```py
from arcpy import da
import os
    
attachTable = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
origTable = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
nameField = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
fileLocation = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)

originCursor = da.SearchCursor(origTable, ['GlobalID', nameField])    
for origRow in originCursor:
    origID = origRow[0]
    origName = origRow[1]

    attachCursor = da.SearchCursor(attachTable, ['DATA', 'ATT_NAME', 'REL_GLOBALID'])
    for attRow in attachCursor:
        binaryRep = attRow[0]
        fileName = attRow[1]
        relID = attRow[2]
if relID == origID:
    open(fileLocation + os.sep + origName + ".jpg", 'wb').write(binaryRep.tobytes())
       
del originCursor
```

Comment: Unless I have misunderstood, it might be as simple as deleting the `break` line and moving your open() line to that indentation? Also thinking about it you have a point with 1 or more attachments, the outer controlling loop should be loop over the points with the inner loop being the attachments.

Comment: Thanks. The script now produces only one attachment. Not sure if I've adjusted it all correct though. I've moved the loops and removed the "break". Kept the if -statement att current place but changed to "if relID == origID".

Comment: Suggest you edit your question and show the new code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below will use the name from the point fc fieldName in the output for multiple attachements, just make sure to assess that all output filenames will be unique going into the same folder, alter below as needed.

```
import os
from arcpy import da

attachTable = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
origTable = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
nameField = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
fileLocation = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)

## dictionary to hold key: GlobalID value: name
pt_dict = {}

## populate dictionary from origTable
with da.SearchCursor(origTable, ['GlobalID', nameField]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        pt_dict[row[0]] = row[1]

## iterate though attachment table
with da.SearchCursor(attachTable , ['DATA', 'ATT_NAME', 'ATTACHMENTID', "REL_GLOBALID"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        ## grab the data blob
        attachment = row[0]
        ## set the naming convention NAME_ATTID_ATTNAME
        ## need to make sure that is output is unique or will overwrite a previous
        ## exported attachment with the same name. If this naming doesnt suit your setup
        ## you could add an incremental counter and add to the filename.
        filename = "{0}_{1}_{2}".format(pt_dict[row[3]], row[2], row[1])
        ## save the file
        open(fileLocation + os.sep + filename, 'wb').write(attachment.tobytes())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will have a try with this as soon possible.